# Stream a PDF file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

**Hi everyone!** I'm working on a Laravel 5.2 application in which the user can download a variety of files. One of these is a 'User guide', explaining how the website is set up and functionalities etc. I would like the PDF to be streamed in another page, so that the user is still within the application. The controller which I am using is:

```
public function userguidePDF(){

    return response()->stream('../public/download/userguide.pdf');

}
```

But this returns:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::__construct() must
>   be callable, string given, called in
>   /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php
>   on line 117 and defined

I have searched on the internet for a method, which leaded me to the following syntax:

```
 return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to find more documentation on the parameters because I don't understand them. Could someone please explain to me what the `$callback, 200, $header` are as parameters and how I can use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#view-responses

```
public function userguidePDF() {

    return response()->file(
        public_path('download/userguide.pdf')
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

$callback should be a function that ouputs your PDF. For example:

```
       $callback = function() 
        {
              $handle = fopen("../public/download/userguide.pdf", "r");
              $filecontent= fread($handle, filesize("../public/download/userguide.pdf"));
              fclose($handle);

              return $filecontent;
        };
```

Comment: And what are the `200` and `$header` ?

Comment: And what is the variable `$filename`?

Comment: 200 is just the HTTP status code (See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success ).

Comment: Oke thank you. Still one question left, what will the `$headers` variable be?

Comment: `$headers` is an array with parameters that get returned to the browser and determine, amongst other things, how it should handle your response. I would look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php for some examples. I would consider at least `Content-Type: application/pdf` as one of the headers in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use download also

```
return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
```

here is the documentation for streaming and also downlaod.
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_stream

**EDIT**

Use headers like this

```
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

Comment: Hi! I have the download working but I specifically want a stream method.

Comment: then you can use the callback example given by @sitethief