# how to download a PDF file that is in base64, controller and view en php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, base64

I have the PDF stored in the database with base64, but I don't know how to download that file with a button in the view

```
<li>
  <body>
    <embed style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="chunk_split(data:application/pdf;base64,{{$item->PDF}})" type="application/pdf"></object>
  </body>
</li>

<li>
  <body>
    <embed style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="chunk_split(data:application/pdf;base64,{{$item->PDF}})" type="application/pdf"></object>
  </body>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an endpoint to stream the pdf to client like these [stream a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860891/stream-a-pdf-file-in-laravel-5-2).

Then you can create an

`<a href="/endpoint/to/download">`